# What is the best way to view large text files from websites?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask, android-webview

I tried `webview.loadurl("www.blahblah.com/blah.txt")` and it crashed after a couple of seconds. What else can I do?

I only want to view these .txt files from the web as fast and as stable as possible.

Also I came across `asynctask` while researching. What is it and can it help me with this?

Also how can I make them to a string if I want to display these text files as a listview item?

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: How large is it? I think you need to download the file to disk first, then read it line by line instead of loading all of it at once from a webview.

Comment: Its not that large maybe 500 kb. Its a really long text.

Answer (score 0):

Asynctask is wrapper for a new thread that allow you to perform network tasks such as downloading.  If you try to download on the UI thread, you will get a crash.

For the text file, download it to disc first, and then read it into memory and display it

```
StringBuilder txtString = new StringBuilder();

try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String textLine;

    while ((textLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        txtString.append(line);
        txtString.append('\n');
    }
}
catch (IOException e) {
//error stuff
}
```

Comment: There are hundreds of txt files that the user can view. I dont want to download all of them. theres not only one.

Comment: Not sure what your use case is, but you could just download a list of the files, and then let the user choose one, and then on user choice, you download that text file and display it to the user.

Comment: what happens to the downloaded text. Will they disappear after a while? They can build up.